# How to send a message from cmd to website with websocket in java?

Tags: java, cmd, websocket

So I have a websocket in java and now I would like to connect cmd to the websocket, so I can send a message from cmd and the message would appear on the website. Are there any commands to connect it, or do you need to add some code in OnMessage?

Every answer is appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please post an [mcve] with a good description where you are stuck.

Comment: Hmm, I just wanna know if there are any commands in cmd to connect to Websocket and to the website, so the message I write in cmd will be displayed on website or, do i need to add some code  to connect website and cmd?

Comment: There are no commands for cmd.exe to connect to a Websocket. However PowerShell does. See `Invoke-WebRequest` and others.